# How long is an open, secure, TCP channel secure?

Tags: security, sockets

We have a web service that acts as a gateway between our clients and another service.  The clients send messages to, and receive random messages from, the third-party service.  The client's server opens a channel to our web server via a secure socket in order to receive the incoming messages (and not have to poll the server every few minutes).

My question is: is it safe to leave this channel open indefinitely, or should we periodically close and re-open it to obtain new credentials (session keys)?  If the latter, how often (hourly, daily, weekly) would be considered "best practice"?  I've found a lot of information on secure communications, but nothing to answer this specific question.

Thanks

Comment: IPSEC definitely renegotiates a session key every hour or so, and I think SSL might do too? From [RFC5746](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5746) it looks like it might need to be initiated by your code, though, notjust happen automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL/TLS (which I'm going to assume you're talking about here) does NOT automatically refresh/renegotiate the session keys being used. There is a renegotiation procedure built-in to the protocol to allow the session keys to be changed within an active session but that procedure was found to have a significant vulnerability a few years back and the renegotiation process was changed ([in RFC 5746, see here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5746.txt)) to resolve the problem. If you do want to renegotiate the session keys for SSL/TLS, make sure you're doing it in the manner described in this RFC.

That does not, however, answer your original question of **IF** the session keys should be changed. The answer is...it depends on your security requirements. A good guideline to be used is that any encrypted communications can be eventually decrypted if you see enough of the encrypted data (how practical/doable this is can vary wildly). So, changing your keys every so often is a very good thing to do. If you're passing a small amount of data over a secured connection and the data isn't that sensitive, then you can get away with doing this on a not-so-regular basis (indeed, your SSL/TLS session is probably going to get broken and restablished due to timeouts on one of the two parties on a somewhat regular basis anyway...). If you've got a very sensitive dataset and you're sending alot of data, then I'd suggest rotating the keys every day or so to mitigate this risk (just do it in a secure manner).